# Redirect from master page to its content pages using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I called this method on keyUp event of enter key

```
   function PerformSearch(search_key) {
                    var url = "<%=ResolveUrl("/Test/TestPage.aspx?type=search&search_key=")%>" + search_key;

                    //GoToLocation(url);
                    //window.open(url);
                    //$(location).attr("href", url);
                    //window.location.replace(url);
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: The page is just reloading @Kuru

Comment: console log the url and see, whether you are getting the correct url

Comment: Yes the url is correct, its working fine with window.open(url), but its opening page in new browser window. I want in same browser window.

Comment: Check the answer..

Comment: okay i'll try thanx :)

Comment: Please add URL after render this "<%=ResolveUrl("/Test/TestPage.aspx?type=search&search_key=")%>" + search_key

Comment: Sorry @GovindSamrow i didnt get you.

Comment: After page has been render , you will get this URL from browser user debugging tool

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
window.location = url;
```

For your reference [read this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm)

Comment: Its not working, again same problem. The page is only reloading.

Comment: How you are calling this function? and are you redirecting to the same page?

Comment: Iam calling this function on pressing Enter key, and is in Master Page. No the page is different.

Answer (score 0):

You have string concatenation errors in your url.

This:

```
var url = "<%=ResolveUrl("/Test/TestPage.aspx?type=search&search_key=")%>" + search_key;
```

Should be this:

```
var url = "<%=ResolveUrl('/Test/TestPage.aspx?type=search&search_key=')%>" + search_key;
```

Comment: No there is no issue in url concatenation, I've tried the code you sent and there is error while using the code you posted.